# Need to understand Javascript Syntax var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

Tags: variables, syntax, timer

Please can anyone help me to understand following line of code?

var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

Thank you

Comment: What about it do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma operator checks all operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand, unless preceded with `var`.

With `var`, it's just declaring multiple variables.

Your code:

```
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
```

Is basically same as:

```
var timer = duration;

var minutes;

var seconds;
```

The last two variables are unassigned.

It's not a good practice to use multiple declaration in this way, so if you have a chance, rewrite this code for clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer - Appreciate.